# Generalizing Cython code for n-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, cython, n-dimensional

I am writing a lot of Cython code that needs to generalize to *n* dimensions (most of the time this will be *n* = 1, 2, or 3).

Take the following code as an example, this is a simple sum of the elements.

```
cimport cython
from cython cimport floating

cpdef floating nd_sum(floating [:, :, :] arr):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t [3] N = [arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2]]
        Py_ssize_t [3] i
        floating total = 0

    for i[0] in range(N[0]):
        for i[1] in range(N[1]):
            for i[2] in range(N[2]):
                total += arr[i[0], i[1], i[2]]

    return total
```

Conceptually, the generalization to *n* dimensions is quite obvious. However, I can't seem to be implementing it in code. I would hate having to basically replicate this code for each case of *n*=1,2,3,...

In general, I also need to be able to access neighbors of each array element in every dimension (think *n*-dimensional kernel convolutions etc), which makes things like flattening the array infeasible.

My main problems are:

- How do I tell Cython to expect an array with arbitrary dimensions as input? I imagine I may have to resort to `np.ndarray` here...
- How can I get an element from an *n*-dimensional array given an array of *n* indices?
- How can I generalize the construct of *n* nested loops? Recursion seems inevitable here, but how do I get access to all *n* indices that way?

Comment: Managing that complexity takes time, even in compiled code.  A lot of the speed you get with `cython` comes from pinning down the dynamic aspects of Python code - creating C code that works just with integers, or just with floats, and arrays with known number of dimensions.

Comment: Could you expand the arrays to be 3D, even if some of the axes have length 1 (`np.atleast_3d`)?

Comment: That could actually work! I had only thought about flattening high-dimensional arrays, rather expanding low-dimensional ones.